# How to accept a type parameter that is only an interface with methods returning Promises, rejecting interfaces that don't?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a function that only accepts arguments that are interfaces which only have methods that return a promise. If an object or interface is used in the type parameter that doesn't meet that requirement, fail to compile.

Example of what I want:

```
interface Foo {
  foo(): Promise<string>
}

interface Bar {
  bar: string
  foo(): Promise<string>
}

// no error
foo<Foo>()

// error
foo<Bar>()
```

To do this I am trying to extend my generic with an object that meets my criteria:

```
export type AsyncMethodInterface = { 
  [key: string]: () => Promise<any> 
}

function foo<T extends AsyncMethodInterface>(): T {

}
```

However this will not accept interface arguments, probably because I am using an interface instead of a typed object

```
interface Foo {
  foo(): Promise<string>
}

foo<T>()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can constrain the checked keys in `AsyncMethodInterface` to just those in the input object.

```
export type AsyncMethodInterface<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: () => Promise<any> 
}
```

See [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIyYAUAlAFzIAKU6AtsAM4QA8jYUoA5gHy4C+uXKEixEKAEJwoOfMgBG0yu04gucoujKUa9JqxXc+goRAAeAB3RQwyMAE8LKAIKN7IBAFkIYABboAEwBJcGh4JBYAFR5kAF5ZAgBtAGsIe2RQZFT7dBhkSIBdSjI4mN0GZhY4EHsYgSEYAFcPMGB0EEJMKORzSBAAxmRXdy8ff2DQsQjonhK8EwB6BeQQLGhaKFxNFgx0WdIhJZ6oDa2uqSh93CA)